# How to plot a histogram for the below specification?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataset in the below format
[image]

Im trying to generate a histogram for the below question

Generate a histogram for the Age feature of all medal winners in the top five sports in
2016

Below is my code for the same

```
df4= df
df4= df4.loc[df['Year'] == 2016]
filter_Age= df4.groupby(['Age','Sport'])['Medal'].count().sort_values(ascending= True)

filter_Age.hist()
```

the output of the same is
[image]

but the expected output is this:
[image]

I dont know where im going wrong! Any help is appreciated

Comment: For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including data as text, [not a picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341), and ask a specific question about it. You'll want to look at the intermediate values to see where they diverge from your expectations. To start, if the year selection works properly, you can ignore all the other data. Then you can check if the groupby is correct, if the count is correct, and if the sort is correct. You might even solve the problem yourself by working through it step by step.

Comment: More tips: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask), [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `hist` count and binned the same column as it was called. What you need is a bar plot. Try something like

```py
(
    df4.groupby(["Age", "Sport"], as_index=False)
    ["Medal"].count()
    .pivot(index="Age", columns="Sport", values="Medal")
    .plot.bar()
)
plt.show()
```

For plotting there are a [few options](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html). Try playing with `stacked=True`, or `subplots=True`

Answer (score 0):

you can use pivot_table and distplot or barplot:

```
filter_Age= df4.pivot_table(index=['Age','Sport'], aggfunc={'Medal':count})
filter_Age= filter_Age.reset_index()

sns.distplot(filter_Age['Age'])
```